# insert multiplication operator in a string where necessary

Tags: python, string

As part of a project I am working on, I would like write to rewrite strings such that:

1. Multiplication should be placed in between number and letter when they are not present.
2. The equation should be equal to zero.

If, Input : `2x+5ydh=4` then output : `2*x+5*ydh-4`

If, Input: `x*3df + d5jk = -12` then output: `x*3*df + d*5*jk +12`

I am thinking of searching for the  positions of numbers and letter separately, and then see they follow each other before fixing multiplication, but is that pythonic enough?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Comment: Please provide a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do something like the following code snippet? Instead of going through and searching for the positions of each digit or letter, just perform it all in one loop, which is more efficient. Basically, we go through the string character by character. If a digit follows a letter, or vice versa, then we add a '*'. Otherwise, continue searching.

Then, to do the '=' part, just assign the negation of the right hand side to the left hand side. This part is a temporary (easy) fix, but if you want a more foolproof fix, you'd have to do some legitimate parsing and evaluating of the right hand side to negate it.

```
def convert(inp: str):
    # Edge case check
    if len(inp) == 0: return inp

    # Go through the string looking for where to place '*'s
    # Add the first character
    tmp = [inp[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(inp)):
        # If letter followed by digit or the reverse, then add a '*'
        if (inp[i].isalpha() and inp[i - 1].isdigit()) or (inp[i].isdigit() and inp[i - 1].isalpha()):
            tmp.append('*')
        # Now add the current character
        tmp.append(inp[i])
    # Convert the resulting list back to a string
    ans = ''.join(tmp)

    # Now if the equal sign is present, split the result 
    # and negate the right hand side
    if '=' in ans:
        left, right = ans.split('=', 1)
        ans = '{}-({})'.format(left, right)

    # Return the answer
    return ans

print(convert('2x+5ydh=4'))
print(convert('x*3df + d5jk = -12'))
```

Comment: Nice one, the part of fixing * operator works as intended, but that of "=" is a quick fix as you've said as it only negates the other side. I shall take it up from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
a = "2x+5ydh=4"
b = "x*3df + d5jk = -12"
def format_equation(inp_str):
    lst = str("".join([c + "*" if (c.isnumeric() and d.isalpha()) else (c+"*" if (c.isalpha() and d.isnumeric()) else c) for c,d in zip(inp_str,inp_str[1:])]) + inp_str[-1]).split("=")
    lhs = lst[0]
    rhs = "+" + str(abs(int(lst[1]))) if int(lst[1]) <0 else "-" + str(lst[1])
    return lhs + rhs
format_equation(a)    # 2*x+5*ydh-4
format_equation(b)    # x*3*df + d*5*jk +12
```

Comment: Great, but it raises an error whenever "=" is missing in the string, I shall fix that.